# Can i install specific sub package from python package such as sklearn

Tags: python, django, scikit-learn

I am developing a Django app, where I need `TfidfVectorizer` and `LogisticRegression` only. But I have to install the whole `scikit-learn` for this purpose. This take space and I want to make the app as light as possible.

So is there a way to install `TfidfVectorizer` and `LogisticRegression` only)

Comment: `i have to install full sklearn on my server. Can I install just these two sub packages`. This seems a bit contradictory. No, you can't.

Comment: I general you can't because those classes will use other classes defined in other places